# Axis client sends three request for each Call.invoke() method

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, axis

Hi I am working on webservice client using Apache Axis 1.4. below is my stub code:

```
SOAPEnvelope soapRequest = new SOAPEnvelope();    
Service service = new Service();

org.apache.axis.client.Call _call = createCall();
        CommonsHTTPSender reqHandler = new CommonsHTTPSender();
        CommonsHTTPSender respHandler = new CommonsHTTPSender();
        _call.setOperation(_operations[0]);
        _call.setClientHandlers(reqHandler, respHandler);
        _call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
        _call.setSOAPActionURI("");
        _call.setEncodingStyle(null);
        _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
        _call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
        _call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);

_call.invoke(soapRequest);
```

while calling the invoke method it is sending the request 3 times.

If I remove the setClientHndler function it will send only once.But I need that function in my code.

Please suggest a method to send single time.

Comment: That means that your handler is somehow making the other two calls. Check your handler class.